# Wordpress ADD FIELD to WP_POST

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have a website made with Wordpress with more than 100.000 post.
The primary search works correctly, but when carried out on the custom fields it is extremely slow.
The only solution is to include the information of the custom fields in some field that I do not use from the wp_post table. I have done it and the search works correctly.
But I want to go a step further and add 2 or 3 fields to the main POST table (wp_post). The fields have already been added, but Wordpress does not recognize them.
What Wordpress CORE files should I modify, or what Hook should I add to register the added fields?

Thank you.

Comment: I think a better way might be to create a dedicated search table with proper indexes.

Comment: It could be populated with _posts and _postmeta data using foreign keys.